# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

in XML

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/map" 
   android:name="in.mpo.mpmobile.KioskListLocation" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

I am trying to load Google Map but unfortunately it show error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttri‌​butes(Unknown
>   Source) at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown
>   Source)

in build File

```
dependencies 
{ 
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') 
  compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar') 
  compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar') 
}
```

Comment: Please add some useful informations about your problem, do not just copypaste the log

Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how a question should be asked

Comment: in XML <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="in.mpo.mpmobile.KioskListLocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
           /> I am trying to load Google Map but unfortunately it show error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source) at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)

Comment: in build File dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
}

Answer (score 0):

change class in your xml

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/map" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

Comment: class i remove my xml file after that i am facing same problem :(

Comment: replace this fragment with your's

Comment: i replace your in place of mine but still get same problem can't be able load map in my application when i test that in Android Studio but using some code in eclipse Map get load. but using in Android Studio Application has been crushed :(

Comment: can you add your class file??

Comment: xml java or build which one class file u need??

Comment: xml and java both

Comment: in xml file<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

Comment: in java file intstatus=GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){int requestCode = 10;
Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
   dialog.show();

  } else {
   SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

   googleMap = fm.getMap();
   googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
   googleMap.getMyLocation();}

Answer (score 0):

Could you please give a try to this?

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</fragment>
```